# What is the name of this logical operator?

Tags: logic

What is the formal name of n-ary logical operator which is true only when exactly one argument is true? For 2-ary case it is `XOR`.

Here is ternary case:

$$Op(A, B, C) = (A ∧ ¬B ∧ ¬C) ∨ (¬A ∧ B ∧ ¬C) ∨ (¬A ∧ ¬B ∧ C)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following papers call this an *exactly-one (EO) constraint/function*:

- [Automatic detection of at-most-one and exactly-one relations for improved SAT encodings of pseudo-boolean constraints](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-30048-7_2)
- [A new SAT encoding scheme for exactly-one constraints](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1288/1/012035)
- [A lower bound on CNF encodings of the at-most-one constraint](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397518305681)
- [A semantic loss function for deep learning with symbolic knowledge](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/xu18h.html)

So it could be called the exactly-one (EO) operator.